# How to install and configure Wireguard

Tags: wireguard

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and Fluxbox  windowmanager.

In my company they have installed Wireguard.

I need your kind assistance to install and configure on my computer, as a Wireguard client.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To install it, open a Terminal and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install wireguard
```

To create the public and private keys, you run

```
cd /etc/wireguard
sudo umask 077; wg genkey | tee privatekey | wg pubkey > publickey
```

Then you need to edit the configuration file by running

```
sudo nano /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
```

And you enter:

```
The client's private key
Own IP
The server's public key
```

To start the connection with the server you run:

```
sudo systemctl enable wg-quick@wg0
sudo systemctl start wg-quick@wg0
sudo systemctl status wg-quick@wg0.
```

On reboot, to check if the connection was made, you run:

```
ping server-IP.
sudo wg
```

Answer (score 0):

However, I've written a bash script which you could use to create and remove Wireguard interfaces and users on your server after installing Wireguard kernel module.
You can get it from my git repository here:

https://github.com/fkia87/wgutil

It's very simple to use. just execute it with `--help` switch and see the manual.

I hope it helps.